# Send Hexadecimal string to socket using python

Tags: python, sockets

Dear friends this is a humble request to solve my problem with example please.
I am working on RFID sensors in which i need to send Hexadecimal data to socket. here is my code

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.0.115' 
PORT = 20108
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
DATA = 'A5 5A 00 08 04 0C 0D 0A'
s.send(DATA)
data = s.recv(4096)
s.close()
d = data.encode('hex').upper()
print 'Received', repr(d)
```

this code is sending DATA in string format but i need to send the DATA in Hexadecimal format because the RFID reader can read Hexadecimal data... i already use struct.pack but it is not working for me or may be I don't know how to use it...
the DATA is same `"A5 5A 00 08 04 0C 0D 0A"` this but how do i send this in Hexadecimal format... for example if sock.send("") sending string. in need to send socket.send(hexadecimal)???

Comment: Looks like you mean a binary pattern, in which case `struct,pack()` is the way to go.  Show what you have done for struct.pack.  You probably want to split the DATA into a list and convert the values to ints.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in hexadecimal type. You will need to serialize that as a string before sending it; as socket.send only accepts strings.

Edit:
After re-reading your question, it seems you aren't encoding the received value as a hex type. With that said, if you choose to serialize your data before sending it, you just unserialize it on the receiving end.

### References:

See Python serialization: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

See Python Hex type: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex

Answer (score 0):

Think this has already been answered
[Pyhton Send receive hex data via tcp socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442704/python-send-receive-hex-data-via-tcp-socket)

You may want to convert your text first into hex format for RFID to understand:

```
'01AF23'.decode('hex')
```

Comment: This solution doens't work. you'll get : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`